# Don't want google to index users in wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, seo, indexing, blogs

I want to disable 'users' indexing by google bot. So, I simply put the following lines in the header area.

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_author() ) : ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<?php endif ?>
```

Does it prevent google bot from being indexed users, and showing users in its SERP?
Does this method have any side-effects? Are there any techniques to optimize google indexing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent google bots only from 'users' page, then it just should be like this:

```
<?php if (is_author()) : ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<?php endif ?>
```

In your code, there is also `is_search` function which checks search results page is displayed or not.

And of course, it does not have any side-effects :)

Answer (score 0):

the [yoast SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin has an option to do this for you.

And google won't use the search function on your site.